# After setting setZOrderOnTop (true) transparency in GLSurfaceview, controls cannot be overlaid on top of GLSurfaceview and will be obscured

Tags: glsurfaceview

The attachment is my relevant code.

Requirement: There are a total of three layers of control layout, with the lowest layer being an ImageView, the middle layer being a GLSurfaceview (with a triangle drawn), and the top layer being a Button

Now I want the lowest level Imageview not to be obscured by the GLSurfaceview, so I need to set the GLSurfaceview to transparent so that I can see the lowest level Imageview. I see that to set transparency in GLSurfaceview, setZOrderOnTop (true) must be set in order to achieve transparency. But when I set setZOrderOnTop (true), the upper control Button will be blocked by the GLSurfaceview, causing the Button text to be unclear. I have found countless methods, but no matter what, I cannot achieve transparency and unobstructed at the same time. I really don't know what to do, please help me, thank you very much!

[This is the demo where the Button is obstructed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4MrZ.jpg)

//xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_GLSurfaceview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:onClick="onButtonTest"
        android:text="按钮"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>

//GLSurfaceView Draw Code
 glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        glSurfaceView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyGLRenderer());

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        RelativeLayout rlCameraARStakeout  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_GLSurfaceview);
        rlCameraARStakeout.removeAllViews();
        rlCameraARStakeout.addView(glSurfaceView, params1);


//MyGLRenderer code
package com.example.opengloverlylayer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    private float[] triangleCoords = {
            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,   // 顶点0
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // 顶点1
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f   // 顶点2
    };
    private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 每个顶点四个字节

    private int program;
    private int positionHandle;
    private int colorHandle;

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleCoords.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, new float[]{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f}, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    }

    private int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }
}
```

`